# How to permanently terminante or delete AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to terminate EC2 instance, however, after a couple of minuets it gets cloned and runs again. It is very annoying. I do not have termination protection for this instance.

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruz3N.png)

[showing termination error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75NLC.png)

Answer (score 2):

Called  support team; got this answer fromAWS and i want to share it with anyone who might have the same issue.

After terminating, the reason the instance gets cloned and re-run again was due to auto scaling group associated to this instance.

As explained to me, every time something happen(stoped, terminated) to the related instance(EC2 in this case), the auto scaling will help to troubleshoot  and bring it back to running state. 
That was the reason I was not able to permanently delete the instance.

> delete the auto scaling by going to the left hand side of the EC2 dash
>   board under AUTO SCALING > Auto Scaling Groups > select the check box
>    Action > delete

After that if you tried to terminate the ec2 instance before, it will be permanently deleted after this action

There was an Elastic IP related to this configuration and had to remove by going

> NETWORK & SECURITY > Elastic IPs > select the elastic ip address >
>   action > review associated addresses are related > go back to Action >
>   release addresses